# Space after Tabular in multicols

Tags: tables, spacing, multicol

I have a multicols enviroment in which the first thing is a tabular and then a bunch of text. The tabular takes about half of the height of the other columns but there is no text below it.[image]

I tried Figure, minipage, medbreak etc but nothing solved the issue.

Comment: Can you show your code? This looks like a mixture of twocolumn and multicolums.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to help without seeing the code you use, but it looks like a combination of the twocolumn-option and the multicols environment.

Example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{multicols}{2}%Here you define a twocolumn-environment inside one columns
\blindtext
\end{multicols}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

You have two columns and inside one of this columns you add the multicols-environment. This may be the source of your problem.

Depending on what you need you may

- Don't use the twocolumn option at all.
- switch to one note layout for some pages (`\onenote` command followed by a `\twocolumn`-command to switch back). (Attention: This forces page breaks)
- Use the `table*`-environment to span the tabular over two columns (The star * is the important thing!)